# Reorder coordinates based on distance from each other in R

Tags: r, geospatial

I have x & y coordinates (black points) that make an irregular rectangle. I would like to order these coordinates so that each point connects to its nearest neighbor in order. If I add lines, the points across from each other connect. [image: Coordinates connected by lines]
[Data](http://modata.ceoe.udel.edu/dev/mcimino/ex_data/xy.Rdata)

```
plot(xy)
lines(xy,col="red")
```

Comment: post output from `dput(head(xy, 15)`

Comment: @42- structure(c(114.466008395264, 114.466010302444, 114.466012209624, 
114.466014116805, 114.466016023985, 114.466017931166, 114.466019838346, 
114.466021745527, 114.466023652708, 114.466025559888, 114.466027467069, 
114.46602937425, 114.466031281431, 114.466033188613, 114.466035095794, 
47.54266335863, 47.5426721405644, 47.5426809224987, 47.5426897044331, 
47.5426984863674, 47.5427072683017, 47.5427160502361, 47.5427248321704, 
47.5427336141047, 47.542742396039, 47.5427511779733, 47.5427599599076, 
47.5427687418418, 47.5427775237761, 47.5427863057104), .Dim = c(15L, 
2L))

Comment: We need a sample of the both "upper" and "lower" values from within the same range of x-values. Maybe try this: `dput(xy[xy[,1] > 114.4660 & xy[,1] < 114.4670, ])`. And paste the output into the body of your question, rather than into a comment.

Comment: @eipi10 you can also download the datafile. Click 'Data' above. this is the output: structure(list(V1 = numeric(0), V2 = numeric(0)), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2"), row.names = integer(0), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Isn't this just a shortest path question? You want the shortest path that connects all the points

Answer (score 4):

Well, it looks like the [Travelling Salesman Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem).

```
library(TSP)
xytsp <- ETSP(data.frame(xy))
colnames(xytsp) <- c("x", "y")
xytour <- solve_TSP(xytsp)
 plot(xytsp, xytour, pch=20, tour_col="red", tour_lty="solid")
re_ordered_xy <- xy[xytour, ]
```

[image: plot of the solution]

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a bit of a Rube Goldberg contraption and I'm not sure how robust it is, but...

The basic idea is that we separate the points into an "Upper" group and a "Lower" group by finding a line that goes between (xmin, y(xmin)) and (xmax, y(xmax)). This will work if none of the y values fall on the "wrong" side of this line. That is, if the points don't have too big a departure from convexity.

Once we have the Upper and Lower points, we sort each group by `x` separately, then we reverse the order of the Upper group so that after we plot the Lower group, the next line will connect to the highest x-value of the Upper group (rather than to the lowest x-value of the Upper group).

```
load("xy.rdata")

# Convert matrix to data frame
xy = as.data.frame(xy)
names(xy) = c("x","y")

# Get range of xy$x; then get xy$y values at min and max xy$x values
x.rng = c(min(xy$x), max(xy$x))
yofx = xy$y[which(xy$x %in% x)]

## Separate points into "upper" and "lower" halves using (x,y) values we just calculated

# Slope of dividing line
slope=diff(yofx)/diff(x.rng)

# Add "dividing line" to data frame
xy = cbind(xy, y.mid = slope*(xy$x - xy$x[1]) + yofx[1])

# Group points into "upper" and "lower" using the dividing line we just created
xy$group = ifelse(xy$y > xy$y.mid, "Upper", "Lower")

## Order the points by xy$group and then by xy$x
xy = xy[order(xy$group, xy$x), ] 

## Reverse order of "Upper" points
# Reset rownames
rownames(xy) = 1:nrow(xy)

# Get range of rownames for "upper" group 
rn = as.numeric(range(rownames(xy[xy$group=="Upper",])))

# Reverse order of "Upper" points
xy = xy[c(1:(rn[1]-1), rn[2]:rn[1]), ]

## Add copy of first point to end of data frame to close the polygon
xy = rbind(xy, xy[1,])

plot(xy$x, xy$y, type="l", lwd=0.8, las=1)
# Add points if you wish
#points(xy[,1:2],col=ifelse(xy$group=="Upper","red","blue"),pch=16,cex=0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, I cant quite get your code to work. Can you reproduce this results based on your code? Also, a warning message appears after "adding diving line to data frame" because slope has a shorter length (1 less) than xy.

Comment: On my machine, the code runs without errors or warnings and produces the graph included in my answer.