# Is it possible to rearrange GPS points based on distance to each other

Tags: r, gis, openstreetmap

I have an array of GPS points I get from Open Streetmap data.
If I create a trace out of these points the result looks like the points are out of "order"

[image]

One approach I tried is: to order those points with TSP as described here:

[Order Points with TSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39459726/reorder-coordinates-based-on-distance-from-each-other-in-r)

what am I doing wrong?
Is maybe a simpler/different solution possible?

Here is the example data and my code for TSP:

```
library(TSP)

trace <-
  structure(
    list(
      counter = 1:29,
      lon = c(
        11.8296776,
        11.8296602,
        11.8296602,
        11.8296602,
        11.8296673,
        11.8296697,
        11.829711,
        11.8297067,
        11.8296776,
        11.830006,
        11.8299073,
        11.8298583,
        11.8298363,
        11.8297687,
        11.8297067,
        11.8310606,
        11.8310617,
        11.8310268,
        11.8309893,
        11.8309043,
        11.8307988,
        11.8305494,
        11.8302034,
        11.8301046,
        11.830006,
        11.8309893,
        11.8310215,
        11.8310483,
        11.8310606
      ),
      lat = c(
        48.1080396999118,
        48.1082178999118,
        48.1083925999117,
        48.1085890999117,
        48.1087772999116,
        48.1088399999116,
        48.1091400999115,
        48.1077663999119,
        48.1080396999118,
        48.1064633999122,
        48.1067714999121,
        48.1069627999121,
        48.107048999912,
        48.1074419999119,
        48.1077663999119,
        48.1033010999129,
        48.1034692999129,
        48.1037970999128,
        48.1040262999128,
        48.1042792999127,
        48.1045636999126,
        48.1051546999125,
        48.1059033999123,
        48.1061551999123,
        48.1064633999122,
        48.1025808999131,
        48.1027420999131,
        48.103014399913,
        48.1033010999129
      )
    ),
    row.names = c(NA,-29L),
    class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

xytsp<-ETSP(trace)
xytour <- solve_TSP(xytsp)
reordered_trace <- trace[xytour, ]
reordered_trace$counter<-NULL
reordered_trace<-rowid_to_column(reordered_trace, "counter")
writeGPX(x =as.data.frame(reordered_trace),filename = "reordered_trace",type = "t" )
```

And the result:

[image]

Here is what I would like to have:

[image]

UPDATE: one approach that seems to be promising:

```
trace$counter<-NULL
my.dist <- function(p1 = c(x,y), p2 = c(0,0)) sqrt((p1[1]-p2[1])^2 + (p1[2] - p2[2])^2)
names(trace) <- c("x", "y")
dists.to.origin <- apply(as.data.frame(trace), 1, my.dist)

reordered_trace <- trace[order(dists.to.origin),]
names(reordered_trace) <- c("lon", "lat")
reordered_trace<-rowid_to_column(reordered_trace, "counter")
writeGPX(x =as.data.frame(reordered_trace),filename = "reordered_trace",type = "t" )
```

This approach works but only for short line:

[image]

UPDATE:
Sadly the approach by Paul approach did not worked either:

**FNAL UPDATE**:
Both provided solutions will work on this short trace.
On a longer trace they will also work but the calculation time
will increase very much. One solution to that I tried was to divide the trace in short pieces and then apply TSP to them.. which make the operation faster, yet produces the wrong result because TSP needs to see all the points to create a correct trace.

[image]

Comment: What is your desired output?  Do the numbers have to stay the same?  What dictates the "correct" order?  Will your real data always proceed Easy-West, for example, or could there be loops in there?

Comment: Hi @PaulStaffordAllen thank you for your time. The correct order would describe a road basically "one by one". There could be loops. Numbers should be rearranged fitting to the gps points so the track creates a line.

Comment: I added an example picture for result.

Comment: OK - how do we know which end of the road is the start?  If there is a loop, how do we know which way to go round it?  If you can explain it with words then it can be programmed, but until you can say what you want it's not possible to confidently advise what is required.  You could arbitrarily select the west-most or east-most point for example, and then work out the distance to all other as-yet-unselected points and choose the closest then repeat, but that would not cope with loops, north-south roads with a bend etc.

Comment: But the points describe a shape and one can see this shape with the eye. Just the order of the points in which those are visited is wrong. Should it not be possible to correct it? to connect the neigbours so to say?  I tried TSP in the code example I provided but it did not helped.

Comment: The reason the TSP attempt failed is probably because TSP implicitly assumes you want a loop (i.e. to return to the start) meaning it doesn't view your path as a single path but rather parts of a loop.  The non-returning version is a "shortest Hamiltonian path" problem.  I think the package `adagio` has a `hamiltonian()` function that can assist - I will see what I can dredge up but check that out in the meantime.

Comment: ah thank you Ill check it out. Check out my Update .. I think im onto something.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252964/discussion-between-paul-stafford-allen-and-andreas).

Comment: Which data from OSM is this exactly? Could it be that you are parsing it wrong? Ways in OSM reference an *ordered* list of nodes. There is no need to rearrange them.

Comment: I use sfnetwork to create a graph where I search for a shortest path from OSM Data (dach...pbf from geofabrik) which I have in postgres db which is imported with osm2pgsql. It seems that the path / trace has parts which are in the wrong order / direction which leads to this problem

Comment: Additional idea to try:  Determine all permutations of the node order, calculate total length for each order, use the lowest.   Permutations will be n! for n nodes so will get unwieldy fast.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but I would step back and consider the source of your data.  If the coordinates represent tracking data, there should be timestamps available which would avoid the need for this analysis.
If they represent points on a road, there should be segments available or at least some form of mapping to indicate edges between these nodes.
Is there a way to query for the data that you actually need?

Comment: Hi Zaq, you are of course correct it's a Data source problem.  Sadly there are no time stamps or anything like this. This data is from Open street network. It's grouped. Each street is divided in separate pieces. Each piece can be transferred to a short gps trace part. sometimes those are in a wrong direction which leads to this problem. I got a solution by getting answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75938726/reverse-elements-of-list-of-data-frames-based-on-the-distance-of-points-within-t  Yet this question here still remains interesting; should it not be possible ..

Comment: to detect a pattern based on a distance between points and reconnect a trace? One can see a pattern with the eye easily so should it not be possible to do the same programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if the code below works for you in general, but I tried it this way with respect to your specific data in the question (doing by selecting a start point into `control` argument)

```
library(geosphere)
library(TSP)

setorder(trace, lat) # sort coordinates by `lat`
tsporder <- solve_TSP(ETSP(trace[, -1]), method = "NN", control = list(start = 1)) # add `start` into `control` to specify the starting point, i.e., the point with the lowest `lat`
tour <- trace[tsporder]
```

and plot it by

```
plot(trace$lon, trace$lat, pch = 20, col = "red", xlab = "Longitude", ylab = "Latitude")
lines(trace$lon[tsporder], trace$lat[tsporder], col = "blue")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but this approach sadly does not work on longer traces as I wrote in the comments and in example code of my question.

Comment: @Andreas I don't know if my update makes sense but you can take a look if it gives you some hints.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I think I have something worth trying:

Follow your example code to create the data frame then:

```
xytsp <- ETSP(trace)

xytsp <- insert_dummy(as.TSP(xytsp), label = "cut")
# this converts to a TSP
# then adds a 'dummy' node to the chart with 0 distance to all other nodes.  
# This is where we will cut to make it a one-way path.

xytour <- solve_TSP(xytsp, method = "farthest_insertion")
# the farthest_insertion method basically finds the end points of the graph (those with the longest distance between them) then
# works out an efficient way to slot the other nodes into the middle
# it is not foolproof for some shapes, but worth a try.

path <- cut_tour(xytour, "cut")
# cut the tour so it doesn't need a return.

reordered_trace <- trace[labels(path), ]
```

then continue as you did above to export/plot as required.

Please let me know if this works for your real examples.

Comment: Sadly this did not worked, see my update with the plot.

Comment: See my other update: the approach I chose works but only for a short trace