# Reverse elements of list of data frames based on the distance of points within the dataframes

Tags: r

I have the following list with dataframes of points:

```
# > trace
# [[1]]
# counter          X          Y L1  id    ref
# 1:       1 12.0165469 47.9982008  1 533 EBE 20
# 2:       2 12.0164185 47.9981120  1 533 EBE 20
# 3:       3 12.0163478 47.9980425  1 533 EBE 20
# 4:       4 12.0162577 47.9979528  1 533 EBE 20
# 5:       5 12.0161357 47.9978117  1 533 EBE 20
# 6:       6 12.0160016 47.9976360  1 533 EBE 20
# 
# [[2]]
# counter          X          Y L1   id     ref
# 1:       7 11.8333238 48.1269572  2 4665 St 2081
# 2:       8 11.8330935 48.1267962  2 4665 St 2081
# 
# [[3]]
# counter          X          Y L1   id     ref
# 1:       9 11.8338450 48.1271528  3 4666 St 2081
# 2:      10 11.8335776 48.1270632  3 4666 St 2081
```

I would like to traverse through a list while calculating the distance between the last point of the current dataframe and the first point of the next dataframe **(distance_1)**,

as well as the distance between the last point of the current dataframe and the last point of the next dataframe **(distance_2)**.

If **distance_1** is greater than **distance_2**, I will reverse the order of the elements in the next dataframe.

Here is how pseudo code would look like:

```
compare<-function(data_frame,next_dataframe){
    
     distance_1<-geosphere::distGeo(p1=data_frame[nrow(data_frame),],p2=next_dataframe[first(next_dataframe),])
     distance_2<-geosphere::distGeo(p1=data_frame[nrow(data_frame),],p2=next_dataframe[nrow(next_dataframe),])
     if (distance_1>distance_2)
        next_dataframe<-as.data.frame(next_dataframe, 2, rev)
 }
 lapply(x, function(x)compare(x,x+1))
```

The desired result would look like this;
Elements of the **dataframe [[3]]** would be reversed

```
# > trace
# [[1]]
# counter          X          Y L1  id    ref
# 1:       1 12.0165469 47.9982008  1 533 EBE 20
# 2:       2 12.0164185 47.9981120  1 533 EBE 20
# 3:       3 12.0163478 47.9980425  1 533 EBE 20
# 4:       4 12.0162577 47.9979528  1 533 EBE 20
# 5:       5 12.0161357 47.9978117  1 533 EBE 20
# 6:       6 12.0160016 47.9976360  1 533 EBE 20
# 
# [[2]]
# counter          X          Y L1   id     ref
# 1:       7 11.8333238 48.1269572  2 4665 St 2081
# 2:       8 11.8330935 48.1267962  2 4665 St 2081
# 
# [[3]]
# counter          X          Y L1   id     ref
# 2:      10 11.8335776 48.1270632  3 4666 St 2081
# 1:       9 11.8338450 48.1271528  3 4666 St 2081
```

Is it possible to achieve this without external packages?

Just with the base R?

Here is the list:

```
trace<-list(
  structure(
    list(
      counter = 1:6,
      X = c(
        12.0165469,
        12.0164185,
        12.0163478,
        12.0162577,
        12.0161357,
        12.0160016
      ),
      Y = c(
        47.9982007999381,
        47.9981119999382,
        47.9980424999382,
        47.9979527999382,
        47.9978116999382,
        47.9976359999383
      ),
      L1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
      id = c(533, 533,
             533, 533, 533, 533),
      ref = c("EBE 20", "EBE 20", "EBE 20", "EBE 20",
              "EBE 20", "EBE 20")
    ),
    row.names = c(NA,-6L),
    class = c("data.table",
              "data.frame")
  ),
  structure(
    list(
      counter = 7:8,
      X = c(11.8333238, 11.8330935),
      Y = c(48.1269571999072, 48.1267961999073),
      L1 = c(2, 2),
      id = c(4665, 4665),
      ref = c("St 2081", "St 2081")
    ),
    row.names = c(NA,-2L),
    class = c("data.table", "data.frame")
  ),
  structure(
    list(
      counter = 9:10,
      X = c(11.833845, 11.8335776),
      Y = c(48.1271527999072, 48.1270631999072),
      L1 = c(3, 3),
      id = c(4666, 4666),
      ref = c("St 2081", "St 2081")
    ),
    row.names = c(NA,-2L),
    class = c("data.table", "data.frame")
  )
)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want iteratively update the order of rows in each dataframe after comparison, which seems a dynamic programming problem. Probably you can use `Reduce` like below

```
library(geosphere)
compare <- function(currdf, nextdf) {
  p <- currdf[.N, .(X, Y)]
  q1 <- nextdf[1, .(X, Y)]
  q2 <- nextdf[.N, .(X, Y)]
  if (distGeo(p, q1) > distGeo(p, q2)) {
    nextdf <- nextdf[.N:1]
  }
  nextdf
}

Reduce(compare, trace, accumulate = TRUE)
```

which gives

```
[[1]]
   counter        X        Y L1  id    ref
1:       1 12.01655 47.99820  1 533 EBE 20
2:       2 12.01642 47.99811  1 533 EBE 20
3:       3 12.01635 47.99804  1 533 EBE 20
4:       4 12.01626 47.99795  1 533 EBE 20
5:       5 12.01614 47.99781  1 533 EBE 20
6:       6 12.01600 47.99764  1 533 EBE 20

[[2]]
   counter        X        Y L1   id     ref
1:       8 11.83309 48.12680  2 4665 St 2081
2:       7 11.83332 48.12696  2 4665 St 2081

[[3]]
   counter        X        Y L1   id     ref
1:      10 11.83358 48.12706  3 4666 St 2081
2:       9 11.83385 48.12715  3 4666 St 2081
```

Comment: Thank you. Im always fascinated to learn a new thing about R. What does Reduce do exactly?

Comment: @Andreas you can read about this http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functionals.html#:~:text=Reduce()%20reduces%20a%20vector,third%20element%2C%20and%20so%20on., much better than what I can explain to you :P